# Is it legal to sell copies from unbranded products?

Tags: copyright, commerce, ownership

If I buy a item on Ebay from China, which says nothing about ownership, brand, legal rights or copyrights, could I legally make copies of that product and sell them commercially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement that an item or seller notify customers that goods are protected by copyright or patent law. It is possible that someone is selling a book which is now in the public domain, which you could legally make copies of. Otherwise, *you* need to determine whether the item is protected.